# What mechanism use an Akka Actor to persist its messages?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Tha Akka documentaton indicates:

> *A durable mailbox is a replacement for the standard actor mailbox that
>   is durable.*

What is the mechanism used as a standard mailbox so an Actor can read its messages after a restart?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a link to the document page ?

Comment: @paradigmatic here's the link: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/modules/durable-mailbox.html

Comment: Isn't it just, as described in the documentation, a file based queue? Are you looking for a reference to/description of the code that implements it?

Comment: @rjsvaljean I think that too. The reader may infer what you say but I think it's not explicit so one can't get to that conclusion. I don't need to get to know the code itself but a description of the mechanism. Regards.

Comment: From 2009: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/akka-user/LqzPGrYJxA8/yrOzFSlm0KoJ and from 2010: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/akka-user/FkXENLfv6OQ ... @rjsvaljean I read your comment with more detail and the documentation indicates " .. to serve as the default durable mailbox implementation." I'm tempted to assume that the mechanism is a queue mapped to a file but What about I/O performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a small project to check this out with my own hands.

The configuration of an Actor's mailbox is achieved via the dispatcher. The following are the possibilities for the mailbox:

```
UnboundedMailbox
BoundedMailbox
UnboundedPriorityMailbox
BoundedPriorityMailbox
```

and finally:

```
Durable mailboxes
```

I had to configure my actor system with a dispatcher which indicates that the mailbox is file based. The following lines were just neccesary in the configuration of the Actor System:

```
my-dispatcher {
  mailbox-type = akka.actor.mailbox.FileBasedMailboxType
}
```

In adition, I configured the properties for the file based durable mailbox, with the indications provided in:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/modules/durable-mailbox.html

Finally, the creator of the specific Actor I wanted to persist in a file creates the Actor with the following:

```
context.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withDispatcher("my-dispatcher"), "myactor1"
```

I still need more practice to make an Actor to be recreated and read the remaining messaged in the mailbox, but the main question is answered now.

Everything was found in the documentation, it was just a matter of getting things done.